# Making image to look as iOS icon programmaticaly

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Hi I have many images in my tableView, and I want UIImage to look as native iOS icon.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Round the corners, put the gloss effect and it's done... There are code snippets for the both actions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the rounded corner, you can do this:

```
[self.myImageView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

**UPDATED**

As mentioned, you need to add QuartzCore framework to make it work